# duplicate checking with form text box in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am storing data from EXCEL user form to excel sheet. i have problem with duplicate checking.

my data in A column like these...
300, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310 so on...

for example user entered 306 on respective textbox then message box will display that "duplicate data entered".

i wrote following code on text box after update, but it is not working. 
any help tqs...

```
Dim Cell As Variant
Dim Source As Range


Set Source = Worksheets("NFLAT").Range("a2:a50")

For Each Cell In Source

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Source, Cell) > 1 Then
  MsgBox "Given number already exists"
End If

Next Cell
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not a question.

Comment: Why are you checking all the cells in Source rather than just the one added ? Is the one added in the range A2:A50 ?

Comment: CDP@1802, great...  my thought is existing number shouldn't allowed. so i wrote above code, but the code is allowing existing value too. i didn't get that where i did mistake. if any better method to check duplicate on user form textbox ...

Answer (score 0):

No need for loop, just check the textbox value. If exists CountIf is > 0 (not > 1).

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    Dim rng As Range, ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long
    Set ws = Worksheets("NFLAT")
    lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lastrow)

    With Me.TextBox1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, .value) > 0 Then
            MsgBox .value & " already exists", vbCritical, "Checked " & rng.Address
        Else
            MsgBox .value & " is OK ", vbInformation, "Checked " & rng.Address
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```